# I understand checkboxes may pass more than one value for further filtering. How can I use two values for the same column for filtering a table in

Tags: django-models

That's my html file:

```
<form action="{% url 'search' %}">
    <div>
<label for="manufacture">Производитель</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="manufacture" name="manufacture" value="Samsung">Samsung <br>
<input type="checkbox" id="manufacture" name="manufacture" value="Honor">Honor <br>
<input type="checkbox" id="manufacture" name="manufacture" value="Huawei">Huawei <br>
<input type="checkbox" id="manufacture" name="manufacture" value="Apple">Apple <br>
<input type="checkbox" id="manufacture" name="manufacture" value="Xiaomi">Xiaomi <br>
   </div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"class="btn btn-primary">
  </form>
```

That's my views.py:

```
def search(request):
queryset_list=Product.objects.order_by('-created')
if 'manufacture' in request.GET: 
    manufacture=request.GET['manufacture']
    if manufacture:
        queryset_list=queryset_list.filter(brand__iexact = manufacture)
 context= {
     products': queryset_list,
 }
 return render (request, 'cart_2/search.html', context)
```

When I check Samsung & Honor at the same time, filtering gives me out only one manufacturer. And I want both. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [`MultiValuesDict.getlist()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) and the [`__in` lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#in).

```
def search(request):
    qs = Product.objects.order_by('-created')

    manufactures = request.GET.getlist("manufacture", None)
    if manufactures:
        qs = qs.filter(brand__in=manufactures)

    context= {
       'products': qs,
    }
   return render (request, 'cart_2/search.html', context)
```

Also (unrelated but) you certainly want to have your brands as a distinct model (with a FK from product to brand) - that's pretty basic relational model normalization, and there are very good reasons to do so.